# Writing test for a Gin API using testify results in a 404 HTTP response code

Tags: go, go-gin, testify

I have attempted to write a test for my [Gin](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin) API using [testify](https://github.com/stretchr/testify).

Unfortunately, it responds with an unexpected HTTP `404` response code within the test.

When I execute the program I can reach the corresponding interface via curl and browser.

Why are my tests failing ?

**Test code:**

```
func (suite *statisticTestSuite) TestGetProjects() {
    suite.T().Log("TestGetAllProjects")

    recorder := httptest.NewRecorder()

    router := gin.Default()

    request, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, "/api/v1/statistics/projects", nil)
    request.Header = http.Header{"Content-Type": []string{"application/json"}}

    assert.NoError(suite.T(), err)

    router.ServeHTTP(recorder, request)

    data := make(map[string]interface{})
    data["projects"] = 3

    respBody, err := json.Marshal(gin.H{
        "code": 200,
        "msg":  "ok",
        "data": data,
    })

    fmt.Println(recorder.Code)
    fmt.Println(respBody)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You create a router without any handle. Add `router.GET("/api/v1/statistics/projects", your handleFunc)`

or

```
func TestHandle(t *testing.T) {
    recorder := httptest.NewRecorder()
    c, _ := gin.CreateTestContext(recorder)

    yourHandleFunc(c)

    fmt.Println(recorder.Code)

}
```